# Hdri seems washed out compared to on hdri haven

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri

Ive always had an issue with hdris not being 100% the same as when I download them but have always found cheats around it by just adding color nodes for the hdri to adjust the gamma exposure etc, but I was wondering if there is a correct way or if its just the hdri.

Hdri I'm using
https://polyhaven.com/a/pink_sunrise

[image]

here's the main issue. It seems that the color in the sky is just washed out, I can bring this back with raising the gamma but then the mountains become too dark, btw I am using agx color space but cant seem to get it the same on filmic either, anyone ever have this problem?

I'm also only planning on using this image as a background (light path-camera-mix shader) so the gamma wont make a difference on the lighting of the scene

Comment: You need to lower the exposure for background hdri. Learn more here: https://hdrmaps.com/blog/realistic-hdri-lighting-for-exterior-archviz-in-blender/